# NativeScript empty Textfield after message is send

Tags: data-binding, nativescript, textfield

html:

```
<StackLayout  class="nt-form chat-wrapper"  >
    <StackLayout loaded="test" id="chat-form" orientation="horizontal" class="nt-input input-field form">
  
   <TextField  
    (textChange)="onTextChange($event)" 
    [text]="inputText"
    width="800px"  
    class="-rounded-lg input" 
    hint="Nachricht" 
    style="background-color: #ffffff;"
></TextField>
        <button width="120px" class="-rounded-lg fa far fas fab" (tap)="sendMessage();" style="margin-left: 15px;" text="&#xf1d8;"></button>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: "ItemDetail",
    styleUrls: ['item-detail.component.css'],
    templateUrl: "./item-detail.component.html",
    providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {
inputText;
constructor(){}
ngOnInit(): void{}

sendMessage(){
        if(this.text == undefined){
            console.log("Sie haben keine Nachricht eingetippt");
        }else{
            this.clearText();
            this._chatService.addMessage(this.id, this.text, this.me);
            
        }
    }

clearText(){
        if(this.inputText != ""){
            this.inputText = "";
        }else{
            console.log("Die nachricht ist schon leer")
        }
    }
}
```

When I send a Message the first Time the text gets cleared. But after that it still sends the Text but it doesnt delet the Message in the TextField.

First Click:

[image]

[image]

SecondClick:

[image]

It still sends the Message but it stays in the TextField box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way to clear it which I find to consistently work is by setting the `TextField`'s `text` property directly.

```html
<TextField #TextField>
  ...
```

```js
@ViewChild('TextField') textField: ElementRef;


clearText(): void {
  // keep this line as you are using it for sendMessage()
  this.inputText = "";

  // clear the textfield
  (<TextField>this.textField.nativeElement).text = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. For anyone Wondering where to find the text property: https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield.html#text
Again thank you!